# Do I have a neutral wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, smart-switch

I am considering purchasing a smart light switch, and I am looking for help to determine whether I have a neutral wire?

My switch box has a bundle of white wires tied off in the back of the box, which looks like the neutrals. However, I also see another white wire going into one of the switches, which left me a bit confused on whether they are actually neutrals?

Here is an image of the switch box. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Comment: Photo seems to be behind paywall/signupwall.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common to have a single white wire being utilized as an always hot feed to a switch. It should, however, be marked with black tape. This is commonly called a switch loop. If you pull out some of these wires, with the breaker off, you'll see that the whit wire from the switch is not bundled in the group of white wires under the red wire nut. Those wires under the red wire nut are your neutrals.